Minimum value of $\frac{x^3}{y\sqrt{x^3+8}}+\frac{y^3}{z\sqrt{y^3+8}}+\frac{z^3}{x\sqrt{z^3+8}}$ if $x+y+z=3$ and $x,y,z \in R^{+}$
I have guessed the minimum is when $x=y=z=1$ however I am not able to exploit it.
I have tried Cauchy Schwarz Inequality and AM-GM, however it was of no avail.
Any hints/solutions are appreciated.

I will outline my solution for you so you can complete it yourself.
As stated, we want to prove $$\frac{x^3}{y\sqrt{x^3+8}}+\frac{y^3}{z\sqrt{y^3+8}}+\frac{z^3}{x\sqrt{z^3+8}}\ge 1.$$
Let $(a,b,c)$ be a permutation of $(x,y,z)$ such that $a\ge b\ge c$. We can easily check that then $\frac{a^3}{\sqrt{a^3+8}}\ge\frac{b^3}{\sqrt{b^3+8}}\ge \frac{c^3}{\sqrt{c^3+8}}$ and $\frac{1}{c}\ge\frac{1}{b}\ge\frac{1}{a}$ therefore by rearrangement it only suffices to prove $$\sum_{a,b,c}\frac{a^3}{a\sqrt{a^3+8}}\ge 1.$$
If $a\ge 2$ then we have $$\sum_{a,b,c}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^3+8}}> \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^3+8}}\ge\frac{2^2}{\sqrt{2^3+8}}=1.$$
If $2>a$ then use the fact that in particular for any $2>t>0$ we have
$$\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^3+8}}\ge\frac{11}{18}t-\frac{5}{18}.$$
